# Local Storage not being set

Tags: javascript, local-storage, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2. Trying to set a string in local storage.

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

constructor(public storage: Storage) {
}


    createChat(chatItem: any): void {
        this.storage.ready().then(() => {
            var jsonString = JSON.stringify(chatItem);
            this.storage.set('chat/' + chatItem.$key + '/', jsonString);
        });
    }
```

However, when I look at Chrome's developer tools, the value is not set.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/storage/)

> When running in the web or as a Progressive Web App, Storage will
>   attempt to use IndexedDB, WebSQL, and localstorage, in that order.

So, it is correct that it is not set: you should look into your Chrome `IndexedDB` instead of a `localStorage`

Comment: Yes, it's there. Thank you very much